# Check different objects for null value

Tags: java, object, if-statement, null

This could be quite a stupid question, but I am not sure how to solve this.

```
int num;
String str;
float flt;
```

I define three variables, one int, one String and one float. Than I do the following:

```
Object a = num;
Object b = str;
Object c = flt;
```

How can I check the a, b or c object for the default value? I know that it is `null` for `String`, `0` for `int`, and `0.0` for `float`, but is there a way to do some sort of:

```
if(a==nullValue(a) && b==nullValue(b) && c==nullValue(c))
```

so that it is equal to:

```
if(a==0 && b==null && c==0.0)
```

I just get the three a, b, c objects passed and so I don't know which type they are.

Comment: Are those initial variables fields?

Comment: Yes they are private non initialized fields in a class.

Comment: What do you mean "I don't know which type they are"?  What is the type of the variable you are using to refer to each?

Comment: `if o.getClass().isPrimitive() then

if clazz.equals(int.class) then return 0 ... and others

else if not primitive return null`

Comment: I get the three objects a, b, c passed to a function: myFunc(Object a, Object b, Object c). So I would do checks like if(a instanceof Integer) { if(a==0) doThis(); else doThat(); } else if(a instanceof String) ... but this looks to complicated and I thought that there would be a way to do this better.

Comment: If you're going to do this elsewhere, write another little function: defaultValue(Object o)

Comment: @MarekRaszewski `o.getClass().isPrimitive()` will never return `true` in this case.

Comment: So there is no standard java function for getting the defaultValue of an object, which could be an int, float, String...?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis your right

Comment: What about using obj.getClass ().isInstace (Integer.class) (or .isinstance short byte etc all types) etc. Then Long.class.cast (obj) == 0.... same for Float/Double. For others object as first line (object == null return true;)

Comment: There's a basic problem here: what if the value was set, but to the default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is a strongly typed language and you are trying to defeat and not utilize one of its core strengths.

Technically speaking, you can achieve what you want, generally you will have to test your `Object obj`  against all possible primitive types + null (since you don't know what this Object *really is* ):

```
     static boolean isDefaultValue(Object obj) {

        if (obj == null // non-primitive
                || obj.equals((byte) 0) // default for byte
                || obj.equals((short) 0) // short
                || obj.equals((int) 0) // int
                || obj.equals(0L) // long
                || obj.equals(0.0f) // float 
                || obj.equals(0.0d) // double
                || obj.equals('\u0000') // char 
                || obj.equals(false)) { // boolean

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

However, instead of doing this, I really encourage you to revise your design and ask yourself why you completely erase data types by casting everything to `Object`. This could lead to unreadable and highly dangerous code.

Post your reason, and we might help you find better solution.

Comment: +1 for using polymorphism here, rather `instanceof` or `getClass`.

Comment: I have a method which returns the value of a field using reflection. Since the attribute could be of any type, my method returns it as an object. When I later want to check if it "has a value" I have to use such a method to cover all possible types.

Comment: ok, perhaps your scenario with reflection is a valid use case. You could use my or David's answer(doing exactly same but with less code). Also, consider, that while extracting attribute value with reflection as you described, you also know its type at this point and could use this type info to check for default of this type right away. I guess it will be tiny bit more performant than looping over 9 possible default type/value tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the class of your choice.

```
private static final List<? extends Object> DEFAULTS = 
    Arrays.asList( null, (byte) 0, (short) 0, 0, 0L, 0F, 0D, '\u0000', false );

private static boolean isDefault(Object o) {
    return DEFAULTS.contains(o);
}
```

Comment: +1 love it. Looks like improved version of my answer. You could also get rid of wildcard and have List<Object> if you cast your null to `Object` explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

For type checking you should use `instanceof` like this

```
Object obj = null;
        int num = 0;
        String str = null;
        float flt = 0f;

        obj = num;
//      obj = str;
//      obj = flt;
        if(obj instanceof Integer){
            //THEN IT SHOULD BE 0
        }
        else if(obj instanceof String){
            //THEN IT SHOULD BE NULL
        }
        else if(obj instanceof Float){
            //THEN IT SHOULD BE NULL
        }
        else{
            //IT IS NULL BECAUSE Object obj = null;
        }
```

It works for any type.

Comment: No, this doesn't work at all.  `instanceof` always returns false if the left hand side is null.

Comment: You are right, if the left side is null then it isn't an instance of anything. But you only have this problem with types that aren't primitive types.